# Perform search with facets unknown upfront Atlas MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, faceted-search

I have the following document structure in MongoDB:

```json
{
  // other keys,
  tags: [
    tagA: "red",
    tagB: "green"
  ]
},
{
  // other keys,
  tags: [
    tagA: "orange",
    tagB: "green",
    tagC: "car"
  ]
}
```

I want to perform a $facets search that gives me the following output (name of each tag + values that occur on that tag + count of these value):

```json
{
  [
    tagA: {
      red: 1,
      orange: 1
    },
    tagB: {
      green: 2
    },
    tagC: {
      car: 1
    }
  ]   
}
```

The tricky part is that the facets are unknown upfront (they can vary), and every tutorial I found only works for a predefined set of facets.

Is it possible?

P.S.: how to get the output of this to come alongside with a given query? So that the return is something like:

```json
{
  queryResults: [all the results, as in a normal query],
  facets: [result showed in accepted answer]
}
```

Comment: Just build you query document dynamically based on the given facets?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider having this as input (i've added bracket around object in your array) :

```
[
  {
    tags: [
      {
        tagA: "red"
      },
      {
        tagB: "green"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    tags: [
      {
        tagA: "orange"
      },
      {
        tagB: "green"
      },
      {
        tagC: "car"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You could then do an aggregation pipeline as follow :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$tags"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "kv": {
        "$objectToArray": "$tags"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$kv"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        key: "$kv.k",
        value: "$kv.v"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.key",
      "value": {
        "$push": {
          "k": "$_id.value",
          "v": "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      val: [
        {
          k: "$_id",
          v: {
            "$arrayToObject": "$value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      res: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$val"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$res"
    }
  }
])
```

It would give you this result :

```
[
  {
    "tagA": {
      "orange": 1,
      "red": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "tagB": {
      "green": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "tagC": {
      "car": 1
    }
  }
]
```

You can see this on mongoplayground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/FZbM-BGJRBm
Hope this answer your question.

Detailled explanation :

1. I use `$unwind` on the `tags` field in order to get one object per object in tags array.
2. I use `$objectToArray` to get keys (`tagsA`, `tagsB`) as values.
3. `$unwind` to go from an array to objets.
4. `$group` with `$sum` accumulator to calculate the occurence of each unique combination.
5. `$group` by `tagsA`,`tagsB`, etc with `$push` accumulator to add value in array (will be usufull afterwards)
6. `$arrayToObject` to go from array to object
7. Same
8. `$replaceRoot` to display results better.

If you want to understand more each step, consider reading mongo doc of each pipeline aggregator i used. You can also use the mongoplayground link above, delete some code to see what happens after each step.

Comment: Dude, can't believe it worked! Thank you so very much! I spent so many hours since yesterday trying to figure it out, but with no luck until now. God bless you! If there's anything I can do for you in return, let me know.

Comment: Just one more thing: how to get the results of a given query alongside with the result you just showed? Explained in details above in a p.s. in this question

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get the results of a given query alongside with the result you just showed?", what query are we talking about ? 

I'll add detail to explain the pipeline in 5 min on the answer.

Comment: The (excellent) answer of yours just returns the facets, right? I would like to have returned the facets alongside with the results of some query. My result JSON would have two keys: "queryResults" and "facets". The "queryResults" key would contain the results of the query, as any normal query on Mongo. The "facets" key would contain exactly the result you showed above. I added an example in my question, hope it explains better.

Comment: For this you can use the `$facet` aggreation pipeline operator, which allows to do  what you want. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/